# How can i execute 2 or more commands in the same ssh session?

Tags: ruby

I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'

Net::SSH.start('host1', 'root', :password => "mypassword1") do |ssh|
    stdout = ""

    ssh.exec("cd /var/example/engines/")
    ssh.exec!( "pwd" ) do |channel, stream, data|
        stdout << data if stream == :stdout
    end
    puts stdout

    ssh.loop
end
```

and i get `/root`, instead of  `/var/example/engines/`

Comment: I have a small related question for ssh ruby. Please help me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799593/unix-commands-work-on-server-but-not-in-ruby-ssh-session

Comment: Too bad plain `Net::SSH` can't execute random scripts.  It looks to me that it is eating new lines somehow and bash cannot work properly... concatenating lines with `;` does not work because comments render useless any commands after them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see if there's something analogous to the file(utils?) cd block syntax, otherwise just run the command in the same subshell, e.g. ssh.exec "cd /var/example/engines/; pwd" ?

Comment: Be aware that semicolon (;) may not work in Windows when joining multiple commands for `system` call, i.e. you shall use `sysetm "cd /var/example/engines/ && pwd`

Answer (score 2):

```
ssh.exec("cd /var/example/engines/; pwd")
```

That will execute the `cd` command, then the `pwd` command in the new directory.

I'm not a ruby guy, but I'm going to guess there are probably more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 2):

In Net::SSH, `#exec` & `#exec!` are the same, e.g. they execute a command (with the exceptions that exec! blocks other calls until it's done).  The key thing to remember is that Net::SSH essentially runs every command from the user's directory when using exec/exec!.  So, in your code, you are running `cd /some/path` from the `/root` directory and then `pwd` - again from the `/root` directory.

The simplest way I know how to run multiple commands in sequence is to chain them together with && (as mentioned above by other posters).  So, it would look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'

Net::SSH.start('host1', 'root', :password => "mypassword1") do |ssh|
    stdout = ""

    ssh.exec!( "cd /var/example/engines/ && pwd" ) do |channel, stream, data|
        stdout << data if stream == :stdout
    end
    puts stdout

    ssh.loop
end
```

Unfortunately, the Net::SSH [shell service](http://net-ssh.rubyforge.org/ssh/v1/chapter-5.html#s3) was removed in version 2.

Comment: I have a small related question for ssh ruby. Please help me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799593/unix-commands-work-on-server-but-not-in-ruby-ssh-session

Comment: James, sorry I haven't logged into SO in a bit, but this looks like the correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28800048/387135

Answer (score 2):

You can just give different commands separated by a new line. Something like:

```
@result = ssh.exec!("cd /var/example/engines/
                    pwd
                   ")
puts @result
```

Its probably easier (and clearer) to pass the command to a variable, then pass the variable  into `exec`. Same principle though.

Comment: This is the best answer for Ruby's net-ssh gem.

Answer (score 1):

Im not a ruby programmer, but you could try to concatenate your commands with ; or &&

Answer (score 1):

There used to have a shell service which allow stateful command like your trying to do in net/ssh v1 but it has been remove in v2. However there's a side project of the author of net/ssh that allows you to do that. Have a look here: http://github.com/jamis/net-ssh-shell

Answer (score 0):

The current location of [net-ssh-shell is changed.](https://github.com/mitchellh/net-ssh-shell)

What I decided to use though to call a random shell script is to scp a file to the remote machine and source it into shell. Basically doing this:

    `File.write(script_path, script_str)
    gear.ssh.scp_to(script_path, File.dirname(script_path))
    gear.ssh.exec(". script_path")`