# Multiple script commands through SSH on Juniper OS

Tags: ruby, ssh, command, carriage-return

My question is concerning networking equipments, especially Juniper OS.
I would like to execute a lot of commands through SSH on the switch.
And not manually, with a script.
But, when I push a command through SSH (example : 'configure') to manipulate software configuration, it changes the prompt indeed.
And the next command, available only in this level of configuration, doesn't work, because the level up is for sure not registrated since last command, so new command = come back to inital prompt.

Example in Ruby with net/ssh :

```
ssh = Net::SSH.start("X.X.X.X", LOGIN, :password => PASSWORD)
   ssh.exec!("configure")  # -> Entering configuration mode
   ssh.exec!("set system services telnet")  # -> error: unknown command: set
ssh.close
```

On Juniper ILC, there isn't '&' or ';' to add mutlipe commands.

Is it possible to insert a carriage return in this kind of command and then put all commands in one request ?

Otherwise how can I execute several commands, keeping the link between them ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i execute 2 or more commands in the same ssh session?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671392/how-can-i-execute-2-or-more-commands-in-the-same-ssh-session)

Comment: Yes, exactly, but it's not the same way to add commands like this. '&&' or ';' exist on Linux, but not on Juniper ILC...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the only solution I found is to concatenate the instructions into one connection.

Example :

```
ssh.exec!('configure;
            set system services telnet;
            delete system services web-management;
            set system login class READ permissions view-configuration;
            set system login class READ allow-commands show;
            ...
            commit;')
```

Hope this will help somebody, don't hesitate to improve it !

Answer (score 1):

I know it's about Ruby but i hope my investigation results in Java could be useful. I used construction like this in [eBay/parallec](https://github.com/eBay/parallec)(i think in JSch it'll work too) :

```
public static void sshVmWithPassword() {
        ParallelClient pc = new ParallelClient();
        pc.prepareSsh().setTargetHostsFromString(HOST)
                .setSshCommandLine("show version;\nshow log")
                .setSshUserName(USERNAME)
                .setSshPassword(PASSWORD)
                .execute(new ParallecResponseHandler() {
                    public void onCompleted(ResponseOnSingleTask res,
                                            Map<String, Object> responseContext) {
                        System.out.println("Responose:" + res.toString()
                                + " host: " + res.getHost()
                                + " errmsg: " + res.getErrorMessage());
                    }
                });
        pc.releaseExternalResources();
    }
```

---